# .NET Regular Expression Help

Tags: .net, regex

I'm trying to validate an input field value that has the following validatino rules:

1. Either a number, OR
2. A number with a trailing 'A', 'K', or 'W'

some valid values : '1', '12', '1A', '12W'
some invalid values : 'A', 'abc', '11A1', '1 A'

Any pointer appreciated. Thx

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you.

Comment: The problem would appear easier if the description said "a number with an optional trailing letter". Also, what sort of a text box? Webforms? MVC? WPF? Windows Forms? Other? And what is a number? How about negative numbers, or decimals?

Answer (score 4):

```
/^\d+[AKW]?$/
```

`\d+` means one or more digits. `[AKW]?` matches one A or K or W, or nothing (`?` could be interpreted as meaning "optional"). The `^` and `$` are anchors that match the start and end of the string respectively.